# Types of Trees in Random Forest

Tags: random-forest, cart

While growing random forest, which kind of trees are used? CART, C4.5 or C5.0 etc. or all of them? So i mean, when we grow random forest, we produce hundreds even thousands of trees, and these trees are produced based on which approach (CART, C4.5, C5.0).

Comment: It depends on the implementation of random forest you are using

Comment: The randomForest() function of **randomForest** package uses CART.

Comment: A more interesting question would be, does the type of trees matter in the overall performance of RF. If yes, which type of construct is better.

Answer (score 1):

> *"which kind of trees are used?"*

This depends on implementation. Generally, any bootstrap-aggregated attribute-bagged learner based on trees (any of them) is called Random Forest. You get different flavors using different trees.

> *"CART, C4.5 or C5.0 etc. or all of them?"*

Any of those can be used to grow a forest. On the last point, though (*"all of them"*), I can't see how much useful it would be. The point of Random Forests is aggregating nearly random generalizations to build a strongly informative one, and I don't think using different tree algorithms would improve this aspect of forests much.

Comment: Actually, i use R for the building random forest "randomForest" function and i use the results in my thesis for that reason i need to explain which tress are used. when i do some researches, generally i saw CART is used for the randomForest in R. But i am not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Function randomForest() in R uses CART algorithm. However, any of them might be used.